# Two column layout for HoloViews plots

Tags: layout, bokeh, panel, holoviews

I have three HoloViews (Bokeh) plots. I want to place them as follows:

```
+---+
|   |
|   +---+
|   |   !
| A | B |
|   |   |
|   +---|
|   |   |
|   | C |
|   |   |
+---+---+
```

that is, on two columns: first column should contain ONLY A, whereas B and C should be in the same column, aligned at the bottom. Any way to do it by Layout and/or Panel?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use Panel to do things like that. Here I'm using an image, but each bit could be a plot:

```py
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

pn.Row(pn.Column(pn.panel('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Hareer_Initiative_Coverage_%282%29.png', width=300)),
       pn.Column(pn.panel('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg', width=300, align='end'),
                 pn.panel('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg', width=300, align='end'), align='end'))
```

[image]

Comment: OK, but once I have a panel, how can I render it? I currently use layout = hv.Layout(); fig = hv.render(layout); show(fig); but if I use a panel instead of an HV layout I get an error message about some "traverse" attribute...

Comment: Panel and HoloViews objects have different APIs; here you'd want `fig = pn.Row(...).get_root()` as described at https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Deploy_and_Export.html#accessing-the-bokeh-model .